# How to evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \epsilon x(\epsilon)$ where $x(\epsilon)$ is the solution of $\mathbf{A}x + \epsilon x = v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> This is an excercise for matrix computations. Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with $0$ as a simple eigenvalue, and given $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. First prove that for sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ is smaller than all the absolute value of nonzero eigenvalues), the equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \epsilon \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$ has a unique solution $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}(\epsilon)$. Then evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \epsilon \mathbf{x}(\epsilon)$ in terms of $\mathbf{v}$ and the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$.

I already showed that the solution of the equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \epsilon \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$ is unique. Since $0$ is the simple eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$, we have $\det(\mathbf{A}) = 0$. Through the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ we can then derive $\det(\mathbf{A} + \epsilon \mathbf{I}) \neq 0$, which shows uniqueness of the solution of this equation.
But for the limit evaluation, I have no idea about how the eigenvectors are related to this. This is an exercise marked with diagonalization, but I don't know how they are related. Maybe there's some properties between the inner products of the eigenvectors?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. $\epsilon x = \epsilon(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}v\implies \epsilon x = \epsilon Q(\Lambda + \epsilon I)^{-1} Q^Tv = Q(\epsilon^{-1}\Lambda + I)^{-1}Q^Tv$ so your desired limit equals $QQ^Tv$, where $A = Q\Lambda Q^T$ is the eigen decomposition of your symmetric matrix $A.$

Note that you need to fill in the gaps here and there to make the proof rigorous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I wonder why $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0 ^ +} \mathbf Q (\epsilon^{-1} \mathbf \Lambda + \mathbf I) ^ {-1} \mathbf Q ^ T \mathbf v = \mathbf Q \mathbf Q ^ T \mathbf v$. When $\epsilon \rightarrow 0 ^ +$, the items in the middle term $\epsilon ^ {-1} \mathbf \Lambda + \mathbf I$ tend to be $\infty$?

Comment: oh  you are right - I confused the limit. In this case, the diagonal matrix in the middle has an explicit inverse: $\text{diag}\left(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + \lambda_2},\dots, \dfrac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + \lambda_n}\right).$ This tends to $\text{diag}(1,0,0,\dots 0)$ since it was given that $0$ was a simple eigenvalue. 

I suggest you write out the details to my answer separately then accept it as the official answer.